# Unit test of generic repository using NUnit and NSubstitute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nsubstitute

How can I perform Units tests, using NUNit and NSubstitute, I want to test inserting a fake "GamaItem" object, and validate that it works, and if the SaveChanges has been triggered.

Im new in unit test, and Im not sure of how can I fake the dbContext object.

Thanks in advance.

Unit of Work:

```
public class UnitOfWork: IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private SRColorContext context = new SRColorContext();
    private GenericEntityRepository<HairColorType> hairColorTypeRepository;
    private GenericEntityRepository<GamaItem> gamaItemRepository;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            context = new SRColorContext();
        }
    }

    public UnitOfWork(SRColorContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public GenericEntityRepository<HairColorType> HairColorTypeRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.hairColorTypeRepository == null)
            {
                this.hairColorTypeRepository = new GenericEntityRepository<HairColorType>(context);
            }
            return hairColorTypeRepository;
        }
    }

    public GenericEntityRepository<GamaItem> GamaItemRepository
    { 
        get
        {
            if (this.gamaItemRepository == null)
            {
                this.gamaItemRepository = new GenericEntityRepository<GamaItem>(context);
            }
            return gamaItemRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;


    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Generic Repository:

```
public class GenericEntityRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal SRColorContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericEntityRepository(SRColorContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if(filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }

    }

    public virtual TEntity GetById(object id)
    {
         return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Comment: Testing that basically guarantees nothing. Most errors will come when the translation from LINQ to SQL fails and those errors will happen in your business layer once you start using a generic repository like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should fake the context object to avoid calling a DB and not the entity (unless you cannot simple create one)

In case you want to write unit tests for *UnitOfWork* class and you're using NSubtitute (or any other .NET OSS Mocking framework) you have to use dependency injection and replace the context instance with a fake instance.

You might also need to wrap the context class - if it's sealed or the methods used are not virtual.